# when minimizing browser, has a white space when scrolling over

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have a problem with my page when I minimize a browser, say horizontally, and theres overflow. When I scroll over to the hidden section from minimizing, my whole page section is blank.

Does anyone know why this happen? I have set my div's to a certain height (i.e. 900px, and not a percentage)?

Comment: It's really hard to tell without markup/css and (**also**) a demonstration.

Comment: How small does the browser have to get for this over flow to happen?

Comment: I have a ton of css, and it looks like theres nothing that usually causes this issue. I was just wondering if someone had encountered this if its a overflow issue or what not. @JamWaffles : it starts happening when it gets to my set width;

Comment: Also, does it matter where `<style type='text/css'></style>` and `<script type='text/javascript'></script>` matter of location? I have a page, say header, with style and script, then I have included another page, say body, with another style and script. Would this be a possible reason of the cause?

Comment: `<style>` is only allowed in the head, but you can use `<script>` anywhere.

Comment: **You need to provide your code**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, that could well be your problem; your fixed width. Try replacing `width` with `max-width`.

`max-width` will behave much the same as `width` while the containing element is that wide or wider, but will allow the `div` to contract when it gets smaller than the width you set.

There's a simple example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rWCAG/). Stretch and resize the bottom right panel to see it in action. If this doesn't work, we'll need to see a page link or a demo on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for you:

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0; /* add some top + bottom padding */
    background-color: #252525;
}
.aligner {
    display: block;
    width: 960px; /* site width */
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
.container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="aligner">
        <div class="container">
            // stuff
        </div><!-- /container -->
    </div><!-- /aligner -->
</div><!-- /wrapper -->
```

It's not the prettiest, but it allows you to throw 100% width background-colors on any section, and works in < IE8. You can do whatever you need to within `div.container` (float, position, etc) and it will expand the .wrapper element (thus expanding your background color vertically). You will not experience white space on the right hand side because the background color is applied to the *wrapper*, which has a 100% width.

Each `div.wrapper` should be treated as a "section" - 'header', 'feature', 'content', 'footer', etc...